# MySQL - Select row count for matching values only querying the last 20 entries

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm trying to run a MySQL query as part of a bash script to find out if the last 19 entries all have the same value (and then do something if so). I have an 'id' row that auto increments with each entry and then the row that holds the integer value, 'number'.

My thought was to try the below however this is limiting the number of rows returned to 19 and as the count only returns one row this doesn't work:

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=uname --database=dbname -s -N -e "select count(*) from table order by id desc limit 19"
```

I need to limit the actual count itself to only check the last 19 rows. I'm not able to say "where id = x to y" as the table will constantly be growing and so the last 19 id's will always be different.

I would be grateful for any help with this one, thanks!

Comment: what output you want exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `limit` is not doing anything in your query.  The aggregation occurs first, aggregating all the rows to produce one row.  Then the `limit 19` is applied, which is useless, because there is only one row.

To get the most recent 19 rows, you will want a subquery, so the following will get you a count of at most 19:

```
select count(*)
from (select t.*
      from table t
      order by id desc
      limit 19
     ) t;
```

If you want to get the number of values of some column, you might want `count(distinct)` instead:

```
select count(distinct col)
from (select t.*
      from table t
      order by id desc
      limit 19
     ) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery.

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sq.number)  
  FROM
  (SELECT number FROM TABLE ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 19) as sq
```

Answer (score 0):

As far what I have understood is that you would always be wanting the last 19 records from the table so,

```
select * 
from 'your table name'  
order by id desc
limit 19
```

and if you want distinct values just then type this:

```
select distinct(column name) 
from 'your table name' 
order by id desc
limit 19
```

Hope it helps you.